# How do I move items from one hash map to another?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am making a virtual zoo. My zoo has a foodstore that contains a range of foods and the quantities of each type of food. Here is my foodstore class:

```
public class Foodstore {

Map<String, Integer> register = new HashMap<String, Integer>();  //hashmap called register declaration

public void addFood(String food, int quantity) {   
    if (register.containsKey(food)) {      //if register contains this food
        Integer newAmount = register.get(food) + quantity;  //assign new amount to newAmount
        register.put(food, newAmount);   //add this amount of the type of food
    }
    else {
        register.put(food,  quantity);
    }

}

public void takeFood(String food) {
    if (register.containsKey(food)) {   //if register contains this food
        Integer newAmount = register.get(food);   //assign new amount to newAmount
        register.remove(food, newAmount);  //remove this amount of food
    }
    else {
        register.remove(food);
    }
}
```

}

I also have an Enclosure class which contains its own food store, here is how I created the enclosure food store hashmap

```
Foodstore store = new Foodstore();
```

In my zoo I have zookeepers who have an aMonthPasses method which needs to allow them to move up to 20 items from the zoo foodstore to the enclosure foodstore. I was wondering how I would go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: On `java.util.HashMap` there is not method `remove(<Key>, <Value>)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `takeFood` method is a little messed up.

I believe you want to pass a `quantity` to your `takeFood` method, the same way you do with your `addFood` method.

With your current code, you check if the map contains your `food` key. If it does not, you try to remove the item with that key, which will not do anything because your map does not contain that key. If your map does contain the `food` key, you are getting the value for that key, and then calling the `remove` function on the hash map with two parameters. However, the `remove` function of the hash map does not take two parameters. That code should not even compile. The `remove` method will simply take the item out of the map with the key that you pass in to it.

What you want to do is get the current value from the map, then if the `quantity` you pass in to your `takeFood` method is greater than the current value, throw some kind of exception or return some kind of message. If the `quantity` requested is less than the current amount in your food store, then decrement the current value by the `quantity`, then put that new amount back in your map for the `food` key. Also, if your `food` key does not exist in your hash map, instead of trying to `remove` a key that does not exist in your hash map, you will want to throw another exception or return some kind of message indicating that there is none of that type of `food` in your `Foodstore`.

Here is what that would look like:

```
public void takeFood(String food, int quantity) {
    if (register.containsKey(food)) {   //if register contains this food
        Integer oldAmount = register.get(food);   //get old amount from register
        if (quantity > oldAmount) {
            throw new Exception("Not enough " + food + " in foodstore. There is only " + oldAmount + " " + food + "."); //there is not that much in the foodstore - throw an error
        } else {                
            Integer newAmount = oldAmount - quantity; //decrement the quantity from the old amount
            register.put(food, newAmount);  //set the value in the hash map to new amount
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("There is no " + food + " in the foodstore.");
    }
}
```

Then in your `Zookeeper` class, I'm guessing you have a reference to your zoo's `Foodstore` and then the `Enclosure`. Then in your `Enclosure` class, it's foodstore would need to be accessible from a public method.

```
public class Enclosure {
    private Foodstore foodstore = new Foodstore();

    public Foodstore getFoodstore {
        return foodstore;
    }
}
```

Then in your `Zookeeper` class, you could move the food around like this:

```
public class Zookeeper {
    private Foodstore zooFoodstore;
    private Enclosure enclosure;

    //constructor to pass in references to the zoo's foodstore and the enclosure
    public Zookeeper(Foodstore zooFoodstore, Enclosure enclosure) {
        this.zooFoodstore = zooFoodstore;
        this.lionEnclosure = lionEnclosure;
    }

    public void aMonthPasses() {
        int quantity = 20; //get the amount of food you want to transfer here
        String food = "meat"; //get the type of food you want to transfer here
        try {
            zooFoodstore.takeFood(food, quantity);
            lionEnclosure.getFoodstore().addFood(food, quantity);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //food didn't exist in zoo foodstore or there wasn't enough
        }
    }
}
```